# Fix for universal reference cannot bind to packed struct fields in gcc/g++ and side effects

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, g++

- This isn't the same as other answers for similar question. They need
  **source code modification in the caller** . This fixes the problem in
  **callee** **without modifying caller's code**. [Passing reference of packed struct member to template. gcc bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29340160/passing-reference-of-packed-struct-member-to-template-gcc-bug)
- This code compiles fine in **clang** without any change but in **g++** it
  throws an error about the packed struct field cannot be bound to a
  reference.
- Also `make_pair(packed_bitfield, packed_bitfield)` gives similar **compile
  error**.
- If the code which calls universal reference function `f` can be
  altered, I can `pass f(static_cast<const int &>(x.i)) or as_const(x.i)`
  to universal reference function.
- The const creates a temporary which is aligned. But in many cases i
  cannot change the calling code.

In what cases will my **fix** fail to work  ? Am i missing any **corner cases** ?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename T> 
int f(T&& args) {
    return args;
}

struct X {
    char c;
    unsigned int i;
} __attribute__((packed));

int main() {
    X x;
    x.i = 3;
    cout <<"x.i= "<<f(x.i)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

```
test3.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test3.cpp:16:22: error: cannot bind packed field ‘x.X::i’ to ‘unsigned int&’
   16 |  cout <<"x.i= "<<f(x.i)<<endl;
      |                    ~~^
```

To fix this add `const T && ref` universal ref and another overload template function `f(const L& arg)` which is only instantiated if L is a non rvalue reference.
The new code becomes

```
template<typename T>
expr_lhs<const T> f(const  T &&  head)
{
        cout <<"in const universal ref ";
        return expr_lhs<const T>(forward<const T>( head )) ;
}

template<typename T,typename enable_if<  !is_rvalue_reference<T>::value   , void >::type* = nullptr >
int f(const T &head){
        cout <<"in const non rvalue ref ";
        return 17;
}
```

compiles and produces output

- 5= in const universal ref 5
- temp rvalue = in const universal ref 0
- rvalue = in const universal ref 3
- i = in const non rvalue ref 17
- x.i= in const non rvalue ref 17

Comment: `__attribute__((packet))` is non standard, so you have to rely on compiler, but [doc from gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-10.3.0/gcc/Common-Type-Attributes.html#Common-Type-Attributes) is very succinct.

Comment: with `const`,  `const T&&` is no longer a forwarding reference.

Comment: While porting code from testing frameworks/measuring perf to another framework, you wouldn't want to change your application code . Idea how would you fix the change in the framework so that the application code works. This is quite different from fixing the application code using const_cast or as_const. Yes it makes it a rvalue ref.

Comment: armcc provides the counter part [`__packed`](https://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armcc/armcc_chr1359124230476.htm) to have pointer to unaligned data, I don't see equivalent for gcc.

Comment: `template<typename T> int f(T x) { return x; }` has no issue neither or `int f(unsigned int x) { return x; }`, hard to tell how to rewrite `f` if we don't know what it should "do"/respect. (Your `const` addition removed the ability to mutate the argument for example).

Comment: Yes but moving by value can be expensive. copying objects by value may not be possible due to deleted copy ctor.

Comment: Do you know the unaligned data type? (if yes, you might add overloads for them). Could you mutate them? (if yes, your `const` trick doesn't handle that (and might also s copy for the aligned temporary)).

Comment: Can you give an example for unaligned data type overload?