# cannot bind packed field 'st.ST::a' to 'int&'

Tags: c++, gcc

using different version of gcc, compile the following code

**g++ (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4)**
there is an error:
main.cpp:21:20: error: cannot bind packed field 'st.ST::a' to 'int&'
int & ref = st.a;

But
**g++ (GCC) 4.4.6 20110731 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4)**

It runs all right.

If I add 'const' before the reference, and modify  test  function,(del t=10),like this.
It runs all right again.

```
const int & ref = st.a
***
int test(const int & t)
{
    return 0;
}
```

**Why?Why?Why?**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

typedef struct 
{
    int a;
    short b;
}__attribute__((packed)) ST;

int test(int & t)
{
    t = 10;
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int a = 1;

    ST st;
    int & ref = st.a;
    test(ref);
    cout << ref << endl;

}
```

I have read
[Passing reference of packed struct member to template. gcc bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29340160/passing-reference-of-packed-struct-member-to-template-gcc-bug)

and

https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=36566

But they didn't say why it runs OK using g++ 4.4.6,but had an error using 4.8.5.
they didn't say why the 'const' can make the code goes right.
This is not a new feature, why gcc has two different results?

Comment: Have you verify alignment for the different version of the compiler?

Comment: with `const &`, a temporary might be created from unaligned int.